FCM Notification in Android: Custom Sound, Banner, and Image Not Working with V1 API
Here is my fcm payload, I cant get a custom sound, white image, and no banner. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, I am using the sound from res/drawable & res/raw. It just gives me the default sound with the correct title and body.
payload = {
                    "message": {
                        "token": device_token_obj.token,
                        "notification": {
                            "title": "App Name",
                            "body": f"{***} from {***} has sent you a message!",
                        },
                        "data": {
                            "type": "new_message",
                            "*_id": str(***),
                            "id": str(***),
                        },
                        # APNs-specific configurations for iOS
                        "apns": {
                            "headers": {
                                "apns-priority": "10",  # High priority
                            },
                            "payload": {
                                "aps": {
                                    "alert": {
                                        "title": "App Name",
                                        "body": f"{***} from {***} has sent you a message!",
                                    },
                                    "sound": "default",  # Play the default sound
                                    "badge": 1,  # Update the app icon badge count
                                    "content-available": 1  # Enable background processing for silent notifications
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "android": {
                            "priority": "high",  # Set priority at the correct level
                            "notification": {
                                "icon": "ic_notification_icon",  # Local icon name (without extension) in res/drawable
                                "sound": "notification_sound",  # Ensure this matches the file name in res/raw
                                "title": "App Name ",  # Add a title for Android-specific notification
                                "body": f"{***} from {***} has sent you a message!"  # Add a body for Android-specific notification
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


I am listening here in React Native, I realized later that Notifee, can't help me with this issue.
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async () => {
});

